# I need to remove the '+id' from a GET form action on submit URL to properly redirect

Tags: php, html

My test page:

> https://www.theartistree.com.au/econnect/

Test Code to enter: `PN61163734`

My current code:

```
<form id="track-ec" action="" method="get" name="track-ec">
    <label for="id">Enter your tracking ID here:</label> 
    <input id="id" name="id" type="text" /> 
    <input formaction="http://www.commsafe.com.au/track+id" formmethod="GET" formtarget="_blank" type="submit" />
</form>
```

The result is this:

> http://www.commsafe.com.au/track+id?id=PN61163734

And I need it to be this without the '+id' included.

> https://www.commsafe.com.au/track?id=PN61163734

I've searched the forums, similar questions etc without luck and would very much appreciate some help to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined it yourself in your own source code that is loaded from your server. it appears in the `formaction` attribute of the submit button of your form. [image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Although I feel a bit stupid, as I though I needed to add the form input (+id) to the url, it is completely worth the result and I very much appreciate the time to assist and guide me. Thank you. Success!